# How to correctly apply global scripts with Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to apply a global fade-in animation to all components in my application. I've added the classname fadeIn to all the elements and set the opacity to 0 by default. I then use js to change that to 1 when the element comes into view.

Below is how I am applying this so far. It does work but there is a major issue and I'm sure it's not the best method and firstly would love to know any better methods.

The major issue is that it only works on the first render. But if I navigate to another page and then come back, all elements are hidden with the opacity 0 and the script does not execute.

Appreciate any advice on how to either solve the current issue, or a better way to execute it.

_app.js

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return <Provider store={store}>
    <Layout>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </PersistGate>
      <FadeIn />
    </Layout>
  </Provider>
}

export default MyApp
```

FadeIn component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Script from 'next/script'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default function FadeIn() {

  const myScript = (
    <Script src='/utils/scripts/appearOnScroll.js' strategy="afterInteractive" />
  )

  return ReactDOM.createPortal(myScript, document.getElementById('doc-root'));

}
```

appearOnScroll.js

```
(function () {
  const faders = document.querySelectorAll('.fade-in');
  const faderOptions = {
    threshold: 1
  };
  const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver(function (
    entries,
    appearOnScroll
  ) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
        return;
      } else {
        entry.target.classList.add('appear');
        appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target);
      }
    })
  }, faderOptions);

  faders.forEach(fader => {
    appearOnScroll.observer(fader);
  });
})();
```

Comment: Just use [nextjs script](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) and mout script in your component. it will be executed when component will render. (in _app, _document, your layout component, page component)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried mounting the script component on pages and in _app, but the result is similar. I think that's what originally led me to trying it as it is now. Are you able to show this in an answer perhaps?

Comment: some time ago i make library which make exactly what you need. You can take a look how i solve this.  [github repo](https://github.com/robert8888/react-on-scroll-animation)

Answer (score 0):

The `_app` component does not rerender in between page transitions, hence your script is not rerunning between pages.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

If you need to execute some code in response to the page changing, use the `router.events` module from `next/router`:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents

You'll likely need to restructure the custom script you've written to execute its logic in response to the route changing (the above link has lots of different events you can pick from that best suit your needs.)

Comment: Good point. . Yes. but if you put it on eg. Layout (which will be render on each page) or we can make some wrapper around page and put it there. (of course is better to refactor this to fit react way).